# Adicionar elemento em JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Essa ação de um botão serve para adicionar o caminho de um arquivo em um `JList`:

```
 private void bArquivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    File arquivo = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    listaarquivos.add(arquivo);
    tArquivo.setText(arquivo.getPath());
    DefaultListModel modelo = new DefaultListModel();
    tListaArquivo.setModel(modelo);
    String l = arquivo.getPath(); 
    if(listaarquivos.size()==1){
        modelo.add(0,l);
        index = 1;
    }else{
        modelo.add(index, l);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Ele mostra o seguinte erro quando o botão é chamado pela segunda vez e assim ele vai para o `else`:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 > 0
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel executar o código e testar o problema.

Comment: Por quê não remove esse if/else e deixe o java cuidar do tamanho da lista para você, utilizando `modelo.addElement(l)`?

Answer (score 0):

Há dois problemas aqui:

- O primeiro é a sua variável `index` ser utilizada desse jeito. Você não precisa dessa variável, basta usar o [método `addElement(E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#addElement-E-). E também não precisa desse `if`.
- O segundo é que você está sempre criando um novo `DefaultListModel` ao invés de usar o já existente.

Além disso, recomendo a você usar os tipos genéricos adequadamente.

Para arrumar esses problemas, primeiro, declare o `JList` assim:

```
private JList<String> tListaArquivo;
```

E se possível, no construtor da classe que tem o método `bArquivoActionPerformed` ou em algum outro lugar que configure o `JList` criado, coloque isso:

```
tListaArquivo.setModel(new DefaultListModel<>());
```

E então, tente isso:

```
private void bArquivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    File arquivo = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    listaarquivos.add(arquivo);
    DefaultListModel<String> modelo = tListaArquivo.getModel();
    tArquivo.setText(arquivo.getPath());
    modelo.addElement(arquivo.getPath());
}
```

Também apague a sua variável `index`.

Finalmente, o uso de notação húngara não é recomendado. Notação húngara é a prática de prefixar nomes de variáveis com informações sobre o tipo ou o contexto no qual ela é declarada, coisa que as convenções de código do Java desencorajam bastante. Assim sendo, ao invés de `bArquivoActionPerformed`, use `botaoArquivoActionPerformed`. Ao invés de `tArquivo`, use `textBoxArquivo`.